# Add tabs in WordPress post manually using pure CSS doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress

I found the pure CSS Tabs that I want to to use in my WordPress posts in https://webdesignerhut.com/examples/pure-css-tabs/.
when I use in my post, it looks messy:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeI46.jpg)

I used this HTML code into Wordpress text editor:

```css
.tabs {
    max-width: 90%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 75px auto;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.tabs:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tabs label span {
    display: none;
}
.tabs label i {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    color: #3498db;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.tab-content * {
    -webkit-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3 {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .tabs i {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .tabs label span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs {
    margin: 50px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content1 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked >
    <label for="tab1">
        <i class="fa fa-html5"></i><span>Tab-1</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content2 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">
        <i class="fa fa-css3"></i><span>Tab-2</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content3 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">
        <i class="fa fa-code"></i><span>Tab-3</span>
    </label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-1 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-1 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content1 -->
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-2 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-2 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-3 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-3 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content3 -->
</div>
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Your tabs are working perfectly. I think your wordpress css is overriding the css of tabs   http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/vyROEV

Comment: Can you post the URL for more details?

Comment: @SantoshKhalse Sorry, I use Xampp for testing.

Comment: which theme you are working?. Are you using boostrap css and js?

Comment: @vel The following is my theme css style http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBYOGK

Comment: I updated above html and css with your theme css. here the link. seems working fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRWGaa

Comment: I have checked with that theme. everything is working fine for me. I thing some plugin css overwriting the css.

Comment: @vel I just use one plugin on my localhost site.

Comment: which  plugin you are using?. and did you using tab anywhere else?

Comment: I think you are not post you code which is used in your theme. I can see there is lot of difference between your code and your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your wordpress theme already contain the class name is tab so use the different class

just rename the **tabs** into **tabs-s**

and **tab** into **tab-s**

It may solve your problem try this..
use like below code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<style>
.tabs-s {
    max-width: 90%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 75px auto;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.tabs-s:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.tabs-s input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
.tabs-s label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tabs-s label span {
    display: none;
}
.tabs-s label i {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.tabs-s label:hover {
    color: #3498db;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.tab-content * {
    -webkit-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tabs-s [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3 {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .tabs-s i {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .tabs-s label span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs-s {
    margin: 50px auto;
    }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs-s">
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content1 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs-s" id="tab1" checked >
    <label for="tab1">
        <i class="fa fa-html5"></i><span>Tab-1</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content2 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs-s" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">
        <i class="fa fa-css3"></i><span>Tab-2</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content3 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs-s" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">
        <i class="fa fa-code"></i><span>Tab-3</span>
    </label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-1 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-1 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content1 -->
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-2 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-2 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Tab-3 Title</h3>
        <p>Tab-3 Content</p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content3 -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: change this class name